# Vertical issues with YouTube modal window, CSS and HTML only

Tags: html, css, dynamic, youtube, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make a modal window that plays a YouTube video. The final result should dynamically resize itself to fill the contents of the viewport while always respecting a 16:9 aspect ratio. It should stop expanding once it has reached 720p.

I'm running into these problems:

1. The video does not respect the height of the viewport if the width is large (overflow)
2. The video is not at all vertically centered

I have no idea at all how to fix these. I have looked for hours at many similar Stack Overflow questions and have not made any progress. Is there any hope?

My HTML:

```
<div id="youtube-overlay">
    <div id="youtube-margin">
        <div id="youtube-container">
            <iframe class="youtube-hd" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NoVW62mwSQQ?rel=0&autoplay=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#youtube-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#youtube-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1280px;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

#youtube-margin {
    margin: 10px;
}

.youtube-hd {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 720px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: And you dont't want or cannot have javascript if I understood right?

Comment: At this point it's worth it to try, honestly.

Comment: Did you fix this already?

Comment: Yes, but I resorted to jQuery. I've never found it as easy to vertically center items in CSS as I do their horizontal counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.youtube-hd {
width:100%;
height:100%;
max-height:720px;
max-width:1280px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
<tr>
 <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
      <iframe class="youtube-hd" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NoVW62mwSQQ?rel=0&autoplay=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

You don't need the `DIV`structure you had.